# add host and ip address to access remote web services in Android

Tags: android, ip, host

I am trying to access a web service remotely(outside the firewall) and i am able to access it from my laptop( where i added IP Address and Host Name) in C:\Windows\System32\drivers\etc\hosts file.

But, i am unable to do the same from an Android App as i don't have a rooted phone. I can root my phone but at the end other users should also be able to use this app. How to achieve that?

What should be the ideal course of action to access remote web services if this app needs to be distributed to end users in the future.
Kindly, advise.

Thanks

Comment: Use just the IP address, why do you need the hostname?

Comment: @DiegoTorresMilano the certificate is stored in the hostname and using direct IP Address works, but the communication becomes unsecured due to lack of certificate.

Comment: don't know what you mean by "stored in the hostname", can you elaborate?